# How to remove something from the slug/url

Tags: url, slug, entry-slug, uri

I got entries in the folder /cms/web/videos/ and the url display this: http://domainname.com/cms/web/videos/barco-auro.

I want it to be this: http://domainname.com/videos/barco-auro.

How do I create clean URLs? I don't find anything on this, or nothing that helps my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Craft 3 under your section config change the URL config

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sections-and-entries.html#sections

SEE: Entry URI Formats

You can select what template it should render and what URL config you want

Failing this you can use something more advanced:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#advanced-routing-with-url-rules

Comment: Thanks, I've done both but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there something wrong with this code?

`code:
return [

    // Route videos/{slug} to a template
    'videos/<entrySlug:{slug}>' => ['template' => 'templates/videos/_entry'],

];`

Comment: What error are you getting? Page not found or Variable "entry" does not exist.

Comment: "Not Found
The requested URL /videos/elia was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Remove templates/ from your template variable, try: 'videos/<entrySlug:{slug}>' => ['template' => 'videos/_entry']

Comment: That also doesn't work. Maybe I have to do something with my folder structure?

Comment: Yeh templates don’t go in the web folder normally. The template folder should be along side the web folder. Shouldn’t be much in the web folder really only index and a few resource filesz

Comment: If everything is working by accessing: /cms/web/videos/barco-auro your rule needs to be:

 'videos/<entrySlug:{slug}>' => ['template' => '/cms/web/videos/_entry']

Answer (score 2):

I'd always defer to a Brad Bell answer, but if for some reason you needed to maintain the URI format and wanted to still customize a route you could use the Routes section of settings. https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#dynamic-routes